# Location of interrupt handling code in Linux kernel for x86 architecture

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt-handling

I am doing so research trying to find the code in the Linux kernel that implements interrupt handling; in particular, I am trying to find the code responsible for handling the system timer.

According to http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=86

> The kernel treats interrupts very similarly to the way it treats exceptions: all the general >purpose registers are pushed onto the system stack and a common interrupt handler is called. >The current interrupt priority is saved and the new priority is loaded. This prevents >interrupts at lower priority levels from interrupting the kernel while it handles this >interrupt. Then the real interrupt handler is called.

I am looking for the code that pushes all of the general purpose registers on the stack, and the common interrupt handling code.

At least pushing the general purpose registers onto the stack is architecture independent, so I'm looking for the code that is associated with the x86 architecture.  At the moment I'm looking at version 3.0.4 of the kernel source, but any version is probably fine.  I've gotten started looking in kernel/irq/handle.c, but I don't see anything that looks like saving the registers; it just looks like it is calling the registered interrupt handler.

Comment: By "architecture independent", you actually meant *dependent*, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I am looking for the code that pushes all of the general purpose registers on the stack

Hardware stores the current state (which includes registers) before executing an interrupt handler.  Code is not involved.  And when the interrupt exits, the hardware reads the state back from where it was stored.

Now, code inside the interrupt handler may read and write the saved copies of registers, causing different values to be restored as the interrupt exits.  That's how a context switch works.

---

On x86, the hardware only saves those registers that change before the interrupt handler starts running.  On most embedded architectures, the hardware saves all registers.  The reason for the difference is that x86 has a huge number of registers, and saving and restoring any not modified by the interrupt handler would be a waste.  So the interrupt handler is responsible to save and restore any registers it voluntarily uses.

See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf), starting on page 6-15.

Comment: I think you're likely right, now that I remember the existence of the iret instruction in the x86 architecture, this seems possible (without this instruction I see no way for the hardware to know when the interrupt handler exits).  Are you aware of the location of any documentation for the x86 architecture that explicitly documents the actions taken by the CPU when it detects the interrupt signal?

Comment: @BenVoight: Thanks for the pointer; your comment in the answer by David Schwartz about the need for the hardware to save the eip register before transferring control to the interrupt handler makes sense.

You mention that the interrupt handler is responsible for saving and storing any registers it explicitly uses.  But what if a process switch occurs as a result of the interrupt being handled?  In that case it seems as if ALL the registers need to be pushed onto the outgoing process' stack; the code that actually manipulates the process control blocks does not seem to do this.

Comment: @ryanmcfall: I don't think they're stored on the thread stack, if they were you could have stack overflow during context switch (yuck!).  Instead, there'll be dedicated space in the thread control block for those registers, and probably `MOV` instructions instead of `PUSH`/`POP`.

Comment: @BenVoight I don't see these instructions anywhere in the `context_switch` function (kernel/sched.c) or the TCB manipulation code (switch_to); the only possibility seems to be in the call to arch_start_context_switch(prev); in context_switch; as best as I can tell, this seems to do:
`PVOP_VCALL1(pv_cpu_ops.start_context_switch, prev);` 
which right at the moment I haven't dug deeply enough to find the correct implementation of start_context_switch.

Unfortunately I probably can't spend any more time trying to figure this out, so for now I'm going to count this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit versions are in `arch/i386/kernel/entry_32.S`, the 64-bit versions in `entry_64.S`. Search for the various `ENTRY` macros that mark kernel entry points.

Comment: Thanks, I found the SAVE_ALL macro in those files; I'm not sure if those are actually invoked by the interrupt handling code, however.  Ben Voight's answer above seems to indicate not.

Comment: @ryanmcfall: It should be evident that it is impossible for an interrupt handler to save the `EIP` register, since it has already been changed to point to an instruction in the interrupt handler.  Same reasoning applies to several other registers which are changed by activation of the interrupt handler.  Other registers must be saved from within the handler, which is an optimization since only registers modified by the handler need to be saved and restored.